# MySQL - calculate row total using a temporary column when select

Tags: mysql

I have a table (4 columns) like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `refer_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `groupType` int(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I create a simple data

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`name`, `refer_id`, `groupType`) VALUES
('a', 1, 1),
('b', 2, 1),
('c', 3, 1),

('d', 4, 2),
('e', 4, 2),
('f', 4, 2),

('g', 7, 2),
('h', 7, 2),

('i', 5, 3),
('k', 5, 3),
('l', 6, 3);
```

I have 3 `groupType`. while `groupType` 1 and 3 is the same (can not group)
and `groupType` 2 (is group with same `refer_id`). 
It looks like

```
id  groupType   group_field total
1           1          1    1
2           1          2    1
3           1          3    1
4           2       group_4 3
7           2       group_7 2
9           3          9    1
10          3         10    1
11          3         11    1
```

I'm using [below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffc5a0/3) query to do that (i think it looks good)

```
select id,
groupType,
IF(groupType != 2, @gf:=id, @gf:=CONCAT('group_',refer_id)) as group_field,
count(*) as total

from myTable
group by group_field
order by id asc
```

And I want to get total rows of above query(`8 rows`) by following, but it is not correct. How to do that? Thanks (I don't want union all)

```
select id,
groupType,
IF(groupType != 2, @gf:=id, @gf:=CONCAT('group_',refer_id)) as group_field,
count(*) as total,

CONCAT_WS('', 1) AS defaultValue,
SUM(defaultValue) as totalCount

from myTable
group by group_field
order by id asc
```

maybe something like ?

```
id  groupType   group_field total defaultValue totalCount
1           1          1    1     1            8
2           1          2    1     1            8
3           1          3    1     1            8
4           2       group_4 3     1            8
7           2       group_7 2     1            8
9           3          9    1     1            8
10          3         10    1     1            8
11          3         11    1     1            8
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Simonare I want to know total of row in my first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
>   `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `refer_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   `groupType` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `myTable` (`name`, `refer_id`, `groupType`) VALUES
> ('a', 1, 1),
> ('b', 2, 1),
> ('c', 3, 1),
>
> ('d', 4, 2),
> ('e', 4, 2),
> ('f', 4, 2),
>
> ('g', 7, 2),
> ('h', 7, 2),
>
> ('i', 5, 3),
> ('k', 5, 3),
> ('l', 6, 3);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select min(id) id,
> groupType,
> IF(groupType != 2, @gf:=id, @gf:=CONCAT('group_',refer_id)) as group_field,
> count(*)  as total,
> count(*) over () as cnt
> from myTable
> group by groupType, group_field 
> order by id asc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | groupType | group_field | total | cnt
> -: | --------: | :---------- | ----: | --:
>  1 |         1 | 1           |     1 |   8
>  2 |         1 | 2           |     1 |   8
>  3 |         1 | 3           |     1 |   8
>  4 |         2 | group_4     |     3 |   8
>  7 |         2 | group_7     |     2 |   8
>  9 |         3 | 9           |     1 |   8
> 10 |         3 | 10          |     1 |   8
> 11 |         3 | 11          |     1 |   8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6634bb902038b4eb8eaefd80fe84bf82)*

For MySQl 5.5+

> ```
> select min(id) id,
> groupType,
> IF(groupType != 2, @gf:=id, @gf:=CONCAT('group_',refer_id)) as group_field,
> count(*)  as total,
> (select count(distinct IF(groupType != 2, @gf:=id, @gf:=CONCAT('group_',refer_id))) from myTable) cnt
> from myTable
> group by groupType, group_field 
> order by id asc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | groupType | group_field | total | cnt
> -: | --------: | :---------- | ----: | --:
>  1 |         1 | 1           |     1 |   8
>  2 |         1 | 2           |     1 |   8
>  3 |         1 | 3           |     1 |   8
>  4 |         2 | group_4     |     3 |   8
>  7 |         2 | group_7     |     2 |   8
>  9 |         3 | 9           |     1 |   8
> 10 |         3 | 10          |     1 |   8
> 11 |         3 | 11          |     1 |   8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11d223b8171b45683d5e99bf6c7a2976)*

Comment: Sorry but I try to get `8 rows` (total of rows)?

Comment: The result has exactly 8 rows. I couldn't understand what you need. What is the expected output?

Comment: sorry for that, i try to get number (`8`) to do paging. plz see my edit

Comment: I try to  run it on `sqlfiddle` but it `error` near `()`? Mybe it depend on MySQL version?

Comment: window functions are supported on MySql 8.

Comment: thankiu so much, b/c i just want to get number `8` to paging rows thank again